# CATEL Button not running Execute Action in UserControl

Tags: user-controls, action, execute, catel

I have a WPF application I upgraded from Catel 4.5 to Catel 5.3. I have a number of UserControls I use for my data entry and editing. I have an Add button at the top of the usercontrol and a datagrid with rows that include an Edit and Delete button. All three buttons use a custom image button. When I run the application and load the usercontrol view/viewmodel, debugging shows the 3 commands are found.

14:33:11:499 => [DEBUG] [Catel.MVVM.ViewModelCommandManager] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yxasm.png) Unregistering commands on view model 'CaddRemoteJobManager.ViewModels.ProjectsViewModel' with unique identifier '3'
14:33:11:501 => [DEBUG] [Catel.MVVM.ViewModelCommandManager] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yxasm.png) Unregistered commands on view model 'CaddRemoteJobManager.ViewModels.ProjectsViewModel' with unique identifier '3'
14:33:11:502 => [DEBUG] [Catel.MVVM.ViewModelCommandManager] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yxasm.png) Registering commands on view model 'CaddRemoteJobManager.ViewModels.ProjectsViewModel' with unique identifier '3'
14:33:11:503 => [DEBUG] [Catel.MVVM.ViewModelCommandManager] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yxasm.png) Found command 'AddProject' on view model 'ProjectsViewModel'
14:33:11:504 => [DEBUG] [Catel.MVVM.ViewModelCommandManager] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yxasm.png) Found command 'EditProject' on view model 'ProjectsViewModel'
14:33:11:505 => [DEBUG] [Catel.MVVM.ViewModelCommandManager] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yxasm.png) Found command 'DeleteProject' on view model 'ProjectsViewModel'
14:33:11:507 => [DEBUG] [Catel.MVVM.ViewModelCommandManager] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yxasm.png) Registered commands on view model 'CaddRemoteJobManager.ViewModels.ProjectsViewModel' with unique identifier '3'

When I click the Add button, the Execute action is never run. When I select the Edit or Delete buttons in the DataGrid, the Execute action is run.

The buttons are initialized as follows...

```
  AddProject = new Command(OnAddProjectExecute, null, "AddProject");
  EditProject = new Command(OnEditProjectExecute, null, "EditProject");
  DeleteProject = new Command(OnDeleteProjectExecute, null, "DeleteProject");
```

This is the XAML for the Add Button

```
      <controls:ImageButton Image="../Images/Add-32x32-32.png"
                        Command="{Binding AddProject}"
                        ImageHeight="32" ImageWidth="32"
                        Height="50" Width="Auto"
                        Content="Add" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                        ToolTip="Add a new project">
  </controls:ImageButton>
```

This is the Execute action for the Add button...

```
private void OnAddProjectExecute()
{
  var vm = TypeFactory.Default.CreateInstance<AddEditProjectViewModel>();
  vm.Project = new Project(string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty);
  MainWindowViewModel.GetViewModel().SelectedControl = new AddEditProjectView(vm);
}
```

This is the XAML for the Edit Button

```
              <controls:ImageButton Image="../Images/Edit-16x16-32.png"
                                  Command="{Binding DataContext.EditProject, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                  ImageHeight="16" ImageWidth="16"
                                  Margin="-7"
                                  Height="32" Width="32" ToolTip="Edit the selected project"/>
```

This is the Execute action for the Edit button...

```
    private async void OnEditProjectExecute()
{
  var vm = TypeFactory.Default.CreateInstance<AddEditProjectViewModel>();
  vm.Project = SelectedProject;
  MainWindowViewModel.GetViewModel().SelectedControl = new AddEditProjectView(vm);
}
```

Any idea why the Edit and Delete buttons work from within the DataGrid, but the Add button at the UserControl level does not. I have the same issue with Save and Cancel buttons in my Edit views. They are also at the top level of the view.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yxasm.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Not sure if you are using Catel "right". You should have to create view models manually (like you do in your command).
2. Did you check whether you have binding errors in your output window? I don't have access to the whole xaml, but my guts tell me your not binding to the right DataContext inside the add button.